# communication of two remote shell scripts through file

Tags: file, shell, ssh, communication

I really need help to understand the strange behavior of my shell scripts.

In fact, I have two scripts running on different nodes. the first script ssh a remote node and launch the second script. the second script computes a cost and send it to the first script. for that the second script ssh the node of the first script (asker node) and write the cost in a file that will be read by the first script (as shown bellow).

the problem is that when the value of cost is 0 the first script continues its execution normally, but if its value is different then 0 the first script remains suspended and doesn't execute the instructions after the ssh.

Does anyone have an explanation for that? 
I can give more details about my code if needed.

Thank you in advance.

First script:

```
....
ssh $remore_node "sh cost_computation.sh <parameters>"
cost=`cat $response_file`
if [ $cost -eq 0 ]
then
    ....
else
    ....
fi
```

Second script (cost_computation):

```
....
computation of the cost 
ssh $asker_node "echo $cost > $response_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this?

First script:

```
....
cost=$(ssh $remore_node "sh cost_computation.sh <parameters>")
if [ $cost -eq 0 ]
then
    ....
else
    ....
fi
```

Second script (cost_computation):

```
....
computation of the cost 
echo $cost
```

Comment: Tanks for your reply. Strangely your code behaves exactly as mine.